# Need to Update User Object data without logged in Back4app Android

Tags: android, parsing, back4app

> I have objectId of User Row now i want to update Email so how can i
> update this without login?. need eargent solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The master key is required to update a User.

What you may do is create a cloud code function and just call it on the Android.

Here's the code that you can use to create your cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("editUserProperty", async (request) => {
    const { objectId, newEmail } = request.params;
    var User = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    let result = await query.get(objectId, { useMasterKey: true });
    if (!result) new Error("No user found!");

    result.set("email", newEmail); //change this line to set a new email
    try {
        result.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
        return "User updated successfully!";
    } catch (e) {
        return e.message;
    }
});
```

After that, just call it in your Android app and it will work.

Here's an example using REST API:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <app-id>" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <rest-key>" \
--data-urlencode "{\"objectId\":\"<your_objectId_here>\",\"newEmail\":\"myNewEmail\"}" \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions/editUserProperty
```

If you don't know how to call a cloud code function in your Android app, you can check this guide: http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions

Comment: Thanks, I dont have any idea about cloud functions. BUT First of i need to check email exist or not in User Object? help me to do this first. then i need to update User object email & name.. its eargent

Comment: help me to go out

Comment: You can deploy this code that I sent to you at Dashboard > Cloud Code Functions and upload it. Then, you'll have a cloud code function in your app. After that, just call it in your app as you can see on the link that I sent in order to help you to do it.